# Could you please rank these in order of how natural you think they are?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

In writing, which of these suggestions are fine? Could you please rank them in order of how natural you think they are?

He sees something moving at the end of the corridor and starts firing his machine gun at it...

...Realizing it was just his own shadow, he stops. (1)

...As he realizes it was just his own shadow, he stops. (2)

...He realizes it was just his own shadow, and stops. (3)

...He stops as he realizes it was just his own shadow. (4)

...He stops, realizing it was just his own shadow. (5)

Comment: Could you give some more context here.  What are you actually doing here?  Is this an exercise?  Are you writing a novel?  Who produced the starting sentence and the five options.  You need to show what effort you have made to answer this yourself.  There should be quite a lot of your analysis here.

Comment: I wrote the starting sentence and the five options. It's for a script. I just want to know what's natural for native speakers and what's not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the "..." are confusing the matter slightly.  It is not clear whether you intend the final choice to be literally including the ellipsis or not.  Stylistically I would probably avoid it, but most if not all your options would be dubious run-on sentences if spliced together with a comma.  So then we have a whole debate as to whether you might prefer to link them with a semi-colon, or have two sentences, and so on.

Setting that aside, I would say none of the five options sounds sufficiently "unnatural" as to be jarring, clearly the output of a non-native writer.  The distinction between them is not one of correct versus incorrect grammar, or even idiomatic versus strange constructions, but only one of style, rhythm, etc.  As such, probably more appropriate for a screenwriting or creative writing stackexchange or forum, than an English learning one.

For example, option 3 mirrors the same pattern as the first sentence.  *He verbs*.  Depending on your taste you might think is a good thing - it creates a sort of poetic symmetry / rhythm by having the two sentences "match".  But you could equally think it is a bad thing - a book would sounding too simplistic and repetitive if every sentence had the same simple cadence.

Similarly, 1, 2 and 3 tell you about the realisation of the shadow before they tell you he stops, while 4 and 5 tell you he stops before telling you why.  You can't really dismiss any of them for being unnatural to natives so which of these is "better" depends only on how much drama / tension you want to create as a screenwriter.